# How can i call a function that executes an fpdf based on the choice of a form selector?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to create FPDF's with different formats, which are inside a file of functions that are called through a form on another page inside the field selector = muni, but it is not respecting me the if and always takes the first function, could you guide me?

This is the form

```
<form id="clientForm" name="formularioDatos" method="post" action="insertBD.php"  target="print_popup" 
  onsubmit="window.open('about:blank','print_popup','width=1000,height=800');">

<div class= col-md-3>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" id="idMunicipio" name="idMunicipio" #>
        <option value="" #>MUNICIPIO</option>
        <option value="ACOLMAN">ACOLMAN</option>
        <option value="ZUMPANGO">ZUMPANGO</option>
    </select>
    <input id="muni" name="muni" hidden="true">
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $("#idMunicipio").change(function () {
    // aqui vuelve a colocar el id de tu select, pero en esta ocación detectamos el valor que tiene el mismo
    $("#idMunicipio option:selected").each(function () {
        // luego guardas el valor en una variable
        var muni = $(this).val();
        $("#muni").val(muni);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is de insertion in db:

```
<?php 

include ("pdffunctions.php");
include("conn.php");
$con = connect();
$muni = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['muni']);
$way_pay = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['way_pay']);
$amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['amount']);
$concept = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['concept']);
$file_name = date("Y-m-d") . "_". $rfc.".pdf";

$sql = "INSERT INTO naucalpan(muni, way_pay, amount, concept, )VALUES('$muni', '$way_pay', '$amount', '$concept', )";
$query= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($muni == 'NAUCALPAN' OR 'HUIXQUILUCAN' )
{
    nau($muni, $way_pay, $concept, $file_name);
}
elseif($muni == 'ACOLMAN' OR 'ATENCO' OR 'AXAPUSCO' OR 'CHIAUTLA' OR 'CHICOLOAPAN' OR 'CHICONCUAC' OR 'CHIMALHUACAN' OR 'NOPALTEPEC' OR 'OTUMBA' OR 'PAPALOTLA' OR 'LA PAZ' OR 'SAN MARTIN DE LAS PIRAMIDES' OR 'TEOTIHUACAN' OR 'TEPETLAOXTOC' OR 'TEXCOCO' OR 'TEZOYUCA')
{
    tex( $muni, $way_pay, $concept, $file_name);
}
```

And here my functions in pdffunctions.php

```
<?php
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    class PDF extends FPDF
    {}

    function nau( $muni, $way_pay, $concept, $file_name){
        
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetTextColor(56,56,56);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
        $pdf->SetMargins(10,10,10,10);
        $pdf->SetY(53);
        $pdf->Setx(45);
        $pdf->Cell(45,12,utf8_decode(''.$muni),0, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Ln();
        $pdf->Setx(45);
        $pdf->Cell(45,12,utf8_decode(''. $way_pay),0, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->SetY(56);
        $pdf->Setx(108);
        $pdf->MultiCell(60, 12, utf8_decode(''. $concept."    TLANEPANTLA"),0, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Ln();

        $pdf->Output('F', "pdfs/$file_name");
        $pdf->Output();
    };

    function tex($muni, $way_pay, $concept, $file_name){
        
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetTextColor(56,56,56);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
        $pdf->SetMargins(10,10,10,10);
        $pdf->SetY(53);
        $pdf->Setx(45);
        $pdf->Cell(45,12,utf8_decode(''.$muni),0, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Ln();
        $pdf->Setx(45);
        $pdf->Cell(45,12,utf8_decode(''. $way_pay),0, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->SetY(56);
        $pdf->Setx(108);
        $pdf->MultiCell(60, 4, utf8_decode(''. $concept."TEXCOCO"),0, 0, 'L');
        
            $pdf->Output('F', "pdfs/$file_name");
            $pdf->Output();
        }
?>
```

Comment: Muni is a hidden field in your form...what have you put in it? According to your html as you've shown it, the field is empty

Comment: Hi again ADyson, i edited my question, forgot add the script, can you helpme please?

Comment: OK I see. Why are you doing that? The value from the select will be sent to the server anyway when you submit...you don't need to copy it

Comment: Anyway your php `if` statements are based on a misunderstanding. `if ($muni == 'NAUCALPAN' OR 'HUIXQUILUCAN' )` must be `if ($muni == 'NAUCALPAN' OR $muni == 'HUIXQUILUCAN' )`, for example. In your version, the OR is evaluated first, so it calculates `'NAUCALPAN' OR 'HUIXQUILUCAN'` as an expression, which evaluates to `true` (because populated strings are truth-y) , so your `if` ends up as `if ($muni == true)` which, with a populated value and a loose type comparison, will always end up being true as well

Comment: I made the changes you told me by adding muni == in each OR comparison and it worked, thank you very much – ADyson

Comment: Ok good. Do you also understand why it needed to be changed? I hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: Yes, it was very clear, I only have one doubt and that is, if there was a less laborious method, because I think I am going around a lot, but for now I will use it like this.

Comment: and it is that I wanted to use bootstrap for the select but I don't know how to pass the value of the id to the post of the form to receive it on the other page

Comment: One idea is that you could put all the allowed values in an an array, and then use `in_array()` to test whether the value given by the user exists in the array. Or you could put them in a database table and see if the value exists in the table.

Comment: As per the HTML you showed us, your `select` has `name="idMunicipio"` so in PHP you'd find the submitted value in `$_POST['idMunicipio']`. HTML forms are simple in that respect - if you set a `name` for a form element, then its value will be sent to the server with that name. Bootstrap by itself doesn't affect how that aspect of the form works, it only makes visual changes. (Of course if you're using some extra plugin designed to manipulate a `<select` or replace it, then that's a different matter...but that isn't what you've shown).

Comment: could you put the answer to my question to qualify it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php if statements are based on a misunderstanding.

```
if ($muni == 'NAUCALPAN' OR 'HUIXQUILUCAN' )
```

must be

```
if ($muni == 'NAUCALPAN' OR $muni == 'HUIXQUILUCAN' )
```

for example.

In your version, the `OR` is evaluated first, so it calculates `'NAUCALPAN' OR 'HUIXQUILUCAN'` as an expression, which evaluates to `true` (because populated strings are truth-y) , so your if ends up as `if ($muni == true)` which, with a populated value and a loose type comparison, will always end up being true as well (demo: https://3v4l.org/FbdIC).